# Unable to get out of terminal window inside VIM using VIM key bindings

Tags: vim

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue :
 1. Open a file in vim (in one window).
 2. Open terminal in a vertical split (in another window).
 3. Move the focus to the terminal's window if you haven't already.
 4. Run some command inside the terminal (like pwd, cd etc.).
 5. Now, you (at least I) can't get back to the file's window using VIM key bindings like (`<C-w>` + h/j/k/l).

Can anyone let me know how I can fix it ?

EDIT: Found the answer. You need to do `<C-\><C-n>` inside the terminal window first to enter the normal mode, then you can navigate across using `<C-w>h/j/k/l`. You can also create a simpler key binding to do that.

Comment: I'm pretty lost on what you're describing. If you're opening a second window, then vim bindings aren't going to do anything to help you switch windows, you'd use whatever your window manager uses (alt+tab for example)

Comment: So with VIM 8+ you can open terminal inside vim (using the :term command).

I meant, open two windows inside a single vim instance, one containing some file and the other containing a terminal.

Now run some dummy command inside the terminal window (inside vim). Now you can't navigation between the windows using <C-w> h/j/k/l.

Anyways, I found the solution from the folks in my company. Will update the post with the answer.

Comment: @SubhadeepSamantaray You should post that as an answer rather than an edit to your question. Please do so.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `<C-\><C-n>` inside the terminal window first to enter the normal mode, then you can navigate across using `<C-w>h/j/k/l`. You can also create a simpler key bindings to do that easily, as shown below:

```
tnoremap <C-w>h <C-\><C-n><C-w>h
tnoremap <C-w>l <C-\><C-n><C-w>l
tnoremap <C-w>j <C-\><C-n><C-w>j
tnoremap <C-w>k <C-\><C-n><C-w>k
```

With the above bindings, you can always navigate using `<C-w>h/j/k/l`, regardless whether you are on an editor window or a terminal window.